# Disable link_to button in Rails after submit to prevent duplication submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I have a modal that pops up when trying to close an object (in this case a call).  The modal pops up with a standard Rails link_to like so:

```
<%= link_to "Close Call #{call.incident_number}", close_call_path(call), :method => :post, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-large btn-block' %>
```

In form objects I'm able to disable the submit button but setting the data attribute of disable_with, but Im not sure if this option is available in the link_to helper.

```
<%= f.button "Update Unit", class: 'btn btn-info', data: {disable_with: "<i class='icon-spinner'></i>Updating..."} %>
```

My goal is to prevent duplication clicks of the button once the action hits the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation, you can use the option `disable_with` as `data` attribute.

> `:disable_with` - Value of this parameter will be used as the value for a disabled version of the submit button when the form is submitted. This feature is provided by the unobtrusive JavaScript driver.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this before with link_to and it wasn't working though it did with button_to.  Come to find out it was an early morning syntax error.  Thanks for your answer!